# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting string python

Tags: python, mysql

You probably have seen it before, but I'm basically trying to avoid MySQL Injection, so I'm formatting my query as follows using Python:

```
if "username" in form:
    username = form["username"].value
else:
    success = 0
    error = "User Name is Missing"

cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE screenName=':1'",[username])
results = int(cur.fetchall()[0][0])
```

This throws an error saying:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: not all arguments converted during string formatting 
  args = ('not all arguments converted during string formatting',) 
  message = 'not all arguments converted during string formatting'
```

Any idea what's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the exact library you're using, but assuming it's *Python DB API* compliant, you probably want to change the `execute` line to this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE screenName=%s",[username])
```

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

The use of `%s` is the current standard in terms of preventing *SQL Injection*. I'm not sure what the post in the answer you linked is getting at there... A couple things to keep in mind about that are that the thread has been closed as "not constructive", and that answer is also ~7 years old, so it's quite possible that there were issues back then that that answer may have been referencing that no longer apply.

But `%s` means that the library (in the `execute` method) handles all the escaping and quoting, and is the way to prevent injection. (As opposed to, say, using regular interpolation, say, via `format`, which would leave it exposed to injection.)

Note that is very specifically **not** `'%s'` and then using `foo % bar` in the `execute` call, but an unquoted `%s` and passing the parameters as the 2nd argument to `execute`.

For example, I use *psycopg2*, which is fully *DB API* compliant, and its [current doc](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) describes using `%s` to prevent injection.

Comment: I could, but it said it was vulnerable to attacks here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks